Two hour time offset for iat in KeyCloak token read by SpringBoot app
I have a SpringBoot app using KeyCloak OAuth2/OIDC for authentication. This works fine when use a KeyCloak instance running on my local machine. Now I've setup KeyCloak using the same configuration on a server in the local network and get the following error:
[invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: The ID Token contains invalid claims: {iat=2024-04-23T13:26:41Z}

The local time during the call was 15:26, so there's a two hour offset. My time zone is CET (GMT+2) which seems to point towards a time zone issue. But I was not able to pin it down so far.
I've checked the following:

Time and time zone on the server are correct (checked by timedatectl)

Time and time zone in the SpringBoot app are correct (checked by LocalDateTime.now())

The timestamp in the JWT (listed below) seems to be correct (checked by calling KeyCloak's /protocol/openid-connect/token endpoint with Postman and reading the access_token with https://jwt.io/).


{
  "exp": 1713879118,
  "iat": 1713878818,
  "jti": "d89131ca-e904-40cc-806f-50496d2abdf0",
  "iss": "http://192.168.252.141:8080/realms/myRealm",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "6ba5043e-9faf-4cbc-914f-bb5623e04bfe",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "myrealm-login",
  "session_state": "a8406003-b6d7-4bd2-8dec-e728c48600b1",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "*",
    "http://localhost:8080/"
  ],
  ...
}

Versions:

KeyCloak 24.0.3

SpringBoot 3.2.4



I did have the same issue. It was because my development system (Windows) clock was not up to date. Although Time and time zone on windows seems correct and also in spring boot app (using LocalDateTime.now()), there must have been some kind of desynchronisation.
I simply went to date/time system settings and click on "Synchronize now" :

right click on clock in taskbar and go to "adjust date/time"
Be sure that you check "set time automatically"
Click on "Synchronize now" under "Synchronize your clock".

I didn't understand why It was not done automatically as i was well in "set time automatically".
